# data frame columns: how can I use loops in this case?

Tags: r, loops

I have a data frame with 2 columns: person and points. In my actual dataset there are more than 1000 persons.

My goal: I need to find persons that have more than 126 points.

df1:

```
person      points
abc
abc        1
abc
abc        2
abc1    
abc1       1
abc1
```

I have used this code:

```
df1 <- read.csv("df1.csv")
  points_to_numeric <- as.numeric(df1$points)

  person_filtered <- df1 %>%
  group_by(person) %>%
  dplyr::filter(sum(points_to_numeric, na.rm = T)>126)%>%
  distinct(person) %>%
  pull()
```

person_filtered

When I enter this code, as a result I get 800 unique persons. But if I want to know how many persons have less than 126 points - I also get 800 unique persons. So it looks like that it does not work.

Comment: This is not reproducible if there is no data for us to use. use `dput(head(df1))` do generate a small test dataset

Comment: your code doesn't work because `points_to_numeric` is not grouped because it is not within the `df1` object, it should be `df1$points <- as.numeric(df1$points)` and then `...filter(sum(points...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use of `summarise` is more idiomatic for this use case.

```
library(tidyverse)

person_filtred <- df1 %>%
  group_by(person) %>%
  summarise(totalPoints=sum(points, na.rm=TRUE)) %>%
  filter(totalPoints >= 126)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I got an error again. Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `totalpoints`.
x invalid 'type' (character) of argument
i Input `totalpoints` is `sum(points, na.rm = T)`.
i The error occurred in group 1: person = "

Comment: looks like you need to coerce `points` to numeric with `as.numeric(points)`

Comment: I have done this already, When I use class(df1$points), I got an answer that points is numeric.

Comment: Please update your question with a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2):

Tidyverse solution. Returns a vector with the persons with more than 126 points.

```
library(tidyverse)

person_filtred <- df1 %>%
  group_by(person) %>%
  dplyr::filter(sum(points, na.rm = T)>126) %>%
  distinct(person) %>%
  pull()
```

Comment: I got this error:     Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
x invalid 'type' (character) of argument
i Input `..1` is `sum(points, na.rm = T) > 126`.
i The error occurred in group 1: person = "

Comment: Try dplyr::filter - there is a stats::filter that masks the dplyr function. I'll update the answer to reflect.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the code below

```
subset(aggregate(.~person,df1,sum), points > 126)
```

or

```
subset(df1,ave(points,persion,FUN = sum)>126)
```